# How to run java class with custom variables from terminal

Tags: java

My scenario:

I have a Main.java file that simply does `System.out.println("Hello")`.
I run it by first, compiling with `javac Main.java` and then excecuting the command `java Main`.

Now what I want is that instead of printing "Hello", it will print whatever the user wants, but *I don't want to change the source code whenever I want a different output*. So I replaced the `System.out.println("Hello")` with `System.out.println(${MESSAGE})`. But this gives error "Cannot resolve symbol MESSAGE".

Ultimately, I want a Main.class file and run with something like `java Main -env MESSAGE=whateverIPutHere` and it should print out whateverIPutHere.

Is it possible?

Comment: `System.out.println("Hello")` in your code will always be printed !

Comment: I hope you understand that the accepted solution really does a detour that isn't required for your simple use case at all. There is zero need to use a jvm property to pass a single string to the main method. And worse: that example code is lacking the required checking to ensure that the property is actually given. As said: the normal way would be to simply fetch a string passed as ordinary argument on the command line.

Comment: @GhostCat yeah I think you're right. I'm kinda a system admin so I'm more familiar with things like system properties, and don't usually give much thought to developers' stuff. I accepted another answer. 
I wonder why none of the Java courses I took taught me that obvious `String[] args` thing. It's like they always start with `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)` :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the input arguments:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
```

And then call it like this: `java Main whateverIPutHere`

Simple as that! `args` is an array containing all the arguments that you pass in the command line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use system properties

```
public final class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("port") + " port");
    }
}
```

And then compile and run

```
javac Test.java
java -Dport=8080 Test
```

Output is : 8080 port

Comment: Thanks. Although all other answers seem to solve my problem (I haven't tried yet), this one is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> Now what I want is that instead of printing "Hello", it will print whatever the user wants, but I don't want to change the source code.

Simply not possible without changing code.

```
System.out.println("Hello")
```

Prints that string. End of story. And:

```
System.out.println(${MESSAGE})
```

is simply not valid Java. If you want to read an environment variable, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) how to do that.

But then: that is really a detour here. You can simply **pass** arguments on the command line:

```
java Main "some string" "and another one"
```

and then retrieve those two strings via the `String args[]` parameter that your main method receives!

The real answer here: you learn a new language by researching how that language works. You don't **assume** how syntax *might* look like, based on experiences from other languages. Meaning: `$ENV_VAR` is a "shell language" concept. Your idea: "maybe Java has the same" is a very inefficient strategy to go about this.

Comment: If you interpret "but I don't want to change the source code" to mean "I don't want to change the source code every time a want to output a different message" then it _is_ possible.

Comment: Thanks for your information. And yeah, like @KlitosKyriacou said, actually I meant "I don't want to change the source code every time I want a different output". Sorry for my confusing question.

Answer (score 1):

You can either read it from args as mentioned above, or, if you know how to add a library to your project, try [args4j](https://github.com/kohsuke/args4j). You'll get way cleaner code as you can use it to separate commandline argument processing to a dedicated class.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, we are printing all the arguments passed from the command-line. For this purpose, we have traversed the array using for loop. The arguments passed in command line is captured by args argument.

```
class test{  
        public static void main(String args[]){  

            for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)  
                System.out.println(args[i]);  

        }  
}
```

compile by > javac test.java

run by > java test sonoo jaiswal 1 3 abc

Output:

sonoo

jaiswal

1

3

abc